# Precompile C# method before executing

Tags: c#, load-testing

I measure code speed like this:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
DoSomething();
sw.Stop();
AddLog("Method speed is (ms): "+sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

But first call of DoSomething() is slow, because code is compiling.
Workaround is measure speed of second call like this:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
DoSomething();
sw.Start();
DoSomething();
sw.Stop();
AddLog("Method speed is (ms): "+sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Is there way to precompile DoSomethig() without first call?

Comment: Can you show us what that `DoSomething` does? I did not get what do you mean by code compiles in the first call. C# is already compiled into IL, so technically, C# code is never compiled at runtime.

Comment: Leri is right: It would be useful with some info about what `DoSomething()` does. Also, I'm curious: How big of a difference are you seeing between the first and second version?

Comment: It is difficult. I take DoSomething() by reflection from any assemblies like: new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.GetMethods().First().Invoke(...).

Comment: And I can not call DoSomethig() twice because it can send Emails, modify databases etc.

Comment: Take a look at [RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbcd4yfw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) maybe can help.

Comment: Wait wait wait .... if `DoSomething()` can mutate databases and notify the outside world when you're *testing* it, I think you may want to rethink your solution here...

Comment: I'll try explain. I want to precompile System.Reflection.MethodInfo

Comment: jdphenix, DoSomething() is test method. If I call it twice it takes more time.

Comment: The documentation does not unequivocally state so, but according to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31316/Pre-compile-pre-JIT-your-assembly-on-the-fly-or-tr) article (among others) you can use the `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod` to precompile a method. NGen is also an option.

Comment: I am trying to do it now.

Comment: @FireShock I posted a code sample as an answer.

Comment: You are more likely to see a speedup here due to caching mechanisms...

Comment: helb, it is good because I am testing methods which will be called many times per second.

Answer (score 4):

> The documentation does not unequivocally state so, but according to
>   [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31316/Pre-compile-pre-JIT-your-assembly-on-the-fly-or-tr) article (among others) you can use the
>   `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod` to precompile a method.

To elaborate on my comment (aforementioned) here is a code sample:

```
static void WarmUp()
{
    var handle = typeof (Program).GetMethod("DoSomething").MethodHandle;
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(handle);
}
```

**Update**

Here is a more generic (although somewhat-brittle) solution that will account for instance members too:

```
public static class MethodWarmerUper
{
    public static void WarmUp(string methodName)
    {
        var handle = FindMethodWithName(methodName).MethodHandle;
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(handle);
    }

    private static MethodInfo FindMethodWithName(string methodName)
    {
        return 
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetTypes()
                    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(MethodBindingFlags))
                    .FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name == methodName);
    }

    private const BindingFlags MethodBindingFlags =
        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;
}
```

Comment: You might be able to make it a bit less brittle by using a lambda expression to define the method rather than a string. I think I'd you made it an expression lambda you could get the methodinfo directly.

Comment: Good idea. I am not experienced with the Expression API though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this difference in time is because the runtime is compiling the method for execution before the first call, while when it is about to be called a second time, everything required for running the method has already been compiled. You can use [ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx) for this task. It compiles il to native exe ahead of execution and will decrease your startup time.

For your specific scenario, I believe ngen.exe to be the right tool for the job, as it can be triggered as a post build event to compile your assemblies ahead of time and be ready when you need them. If you use PrepareMethod, then you will still have the delay JITing the methods when you *run* your tests, just not when actually calling them.

Comment: In my case it is not the best way because my task is a part of unit-testing (TestClass, TestMethod).

Comment: You can still use ngen.exe in the post-compile phase of your application to precompile your test assembly. Assemblies that are compiled simply have their compiled bytecode stored in a local cache. You should still be able to test your code.